# mysql select number of row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**PlayerLeague**

- league_id
- player_id
- player_position

**PlayerStat**

- player_id
- score

I have two tables, and I want to update PlayerLeague, set player_position equal row number in:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerStat s JOIN PlayerLeague l 
ON s.player_id=l.player_id WHERE l.league_id=3 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

I tried to use @i in my select, but with join ORDER BY was ignored.

**UPDATE**

So, now I have this and it's working, but I'm not sure that it's normal way.
It will be run every hour for three leagues 40-500 players.

```
SET @i=0;
UPDATE PlayerLeague ll set ll.player_position = ( SELECT position FROM (SELECT
s.player_id, @i:=@i+1 as position
FROM PlayerStat s
where s.player_id in
  (SELECT player_id from PlayerLeague l WHERE l.league_id = 3)
  ORDER BY score DESC) AS t WHERE t.player_id=ll.player_id);
```

Comment: "but with join ORDER BY was ignored." --- it's not ignored. `ORDER BY` sorts by whatever expression or column you're passing to it

Comment: How many rows with l.league_id=3 do you have?

Comment: Mihai, I have 3 leagues, from 40 to ~500 players

Comment: would you include sample data?

Comment: Your task would be much more simple if you had `score` in `PlayerLeague` table, not in a separate one. Is there a reason for such design? What I mean is that MySQL does not allow `UPDATE ... JOIN ... ORDER BY` queries, but is perfectly fine with `UPDATE ... ORDER BY` without joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meet this little cute monster:

```sql
UPDATE PlayerLeague AS l
    JOIN (
        SELECT p.player_id, @i := @i + 1 AS player_position
        FROM (
            SELECT ss.player_id
            FROM PlayerStat AS ss
                JOIN PlayerLeague AS ll
                    ON ss.player_id=ll.player_id
            WHERE ll.league_id=3
            ORDER BY ss.score DESC
        ) AS p, (SELECT @i := 0) AS tmp
    ) AS s ON s.player_id=l.player_id
SET l.player_position = s.player_position
```

So, what's happening here?

- Innermost query selects all players in a league in order of their scores.
- It is wrapped in a query that adds row counts.
- Finally, the outer UPDATE does what you need: adds row counts into PlayerLeague table.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT *
  FROM PlayerStat s
 where s.player_id in
       (select player_id from PlayerLeague l WHERE l.league_id = 3)
 ORDER BY score DESC;
```